# Verifying Signature of Debian 10.5 returns error "Can't check signature: No public key"

Tags: debian, gpg, signature

I'm trying to verify the SHA512 checksum for `Debian 10.5-amd-netinst.iso` as found [on the official Debian CD-image site](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/).

I'm running into the following error:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring Debian\ CD\ signing\ key\ \(6294BE9B\)\ –\ Public.asc --verify SHA512SUMS.sign
gpg: assuming signed data in 'SHA512SUMS'
gpg: Signature made Sat  1 Aug 22:01:33 2020 EDT
gpg:                using RSA key DF9B9C49EAA9298432589D76DA87E80D6294BE9B
gpg: key DA87E80D6294BE9B: new key but contains no user ID - skipped
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Looking across the web and other posts, a few people suggested using different keyring servers to retrieve the key because some of them have an owner approval system that will strip all user IDs unless the owner of the corresponding email address has allowed them to be published. I've tried a dozen different key servers and none of them seem to solve the issue.

Any thoughts on what the issue could be or how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GnuPG `--keyring` argument doesn't accept an ASCII-armored file as input.  The easiest way to verify this is to do this:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys DF9B9C49EAA9298432589D76DA87E80D6294BE9B
$ gpg --no-armor -o keyring.gpg --export DF9B9C49EAA9298432589D76DA87E80D6294BE9B
$ gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring keyring.gpg --keyserver-options none --verify SHA512SUMS.sign
```

Do note that you can also use `gpgv` to verify data if you want to restrict verification to a specific set of keyrings and not fetch the keys from a keyserver if they're missing.  If you're looking into doing this in a program and need more than the exit status, `--status-fd` is your friend.